# Nexus Blobstore on AWS S3 via Terraform: Error: could not read blobstore of type "S3": HTTP: 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, kubernetes-helm, nexus

I just upgraded my Nexus on my Kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS using Helm via Terraform and I started getting the following error:

```
Error: could not read blobstore "nexus-bucket-staging" of type "S3": HTTP: 404
```

Versions comparison table is below:

| Version | Nexus App Version | Helm Nexus Chart Version | Helm Nexus Chart Name | Helm Nexus Chart Repository |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Old | `3.29.0` | `4.1.0` | `sonatype-nexus` | `https://oteemo.github.io/charts` |
| New | `3.58.1` | `58.1.0` | `nexus-repository-manager` | `https://sonatype.github.io/helm3-charts` |

Terraform Version: `v0.14.11`

Terraform Provider for Nexus Link: [Terraform > Nexus Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/datadrivers/nexus/latest/docs)

Terraform Provider for Nexus Version: `v1.12.0`

**What is the reason? How to fix it? It was working fine before and I didn't change anything in the blobstore Terraform resource.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your Terraform provider for Nexus to a later version, for example, to version `1.21.2`.

Most probably the newer Nexus version doesn't work well with the older Terraform provider for Nexus.

Comment: What is `insecure = true`? Stuff like that should never be in an answer without a huge disclaimer and explanation.

Comment: @luk2302 insecure is a Boolean to specify wether insecure SSL connections are allowed or not. Reading environment variable NEXUS_INSECURE_SKIP_VERIFY. Default:true. Reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/datadrivers/nexus/latest/docs#insecure So, including it wasn't necessary. I updated his answer but upgrading Terraform provider for Nexus fixed the issue.